# react local-storage not refreshing

Tags: reactjs

so i have this data set to local-storage within eh main component and then im calling generating a card which is another component. then im recalling that storage in a component to add it into a chart, im getting the data but it only updates when i refresh the page and not when i select a new item from the list.

```
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=100")
  .then((response) => {
    let pokemons = response.data.results;
    const pokeData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
      pokeData.push({
        name: pokemons[i].name,
        url: pokemons[i].url,
      });
    }
    let startItem = pokeData.map((item) => (
      <Card pname={item.name} plink={item.url} />
    ));
    setgenPokeListItem(startItem);


  });

axios
  .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=100")
  .then((response) => {
    let pokemons = response.data.results;
    const pokeData2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
      pokeData2.push({
        name: pokemons[i].name,
        url: pokemons[i].url,
      });
    }
    let battleItem = pokeData2.map((item) => (
      <PokeListItem2 pname={item.name} plink={item.url} />
    ));
    setgenPokeListItem2(battleItem);
  });
  setPokeStats(localStorage.getItem("PokemonOne").split(','));
  // setPokeStats2(localStorage.getItem("PokemonTwo").split(','));
 }, []);

const data = {
labels,
datasets: [
  {
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    data: pokeStats,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
  },
  {
    label: 'Dataset 2',
    data: pokeStats2,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
  },
],
};
```